# Filo vs agapas in the dialog of Peter with resurrected Jesus, a linguistic detail

Tags: greek, hebrew, john, aramaic, peter

In John 21:15-17 the deep meaning of the text is revealed by using different words to express love: filo (like) and agapas (love). I think, Peter was grieved by the meaning of the text about words of Jesus changing from love to like.

But it is unclear how this can be expressed in Jewish or Aramaic language. I can also expect that Peter and resurrected Jesus spoke in Greek.

But in the case that they didn't use Greek, how the difference between filo and agapas could (or could not) be expressed in the language that they used?

Comment: There is a large literature on this subject - some believe that the difference is insignificant and other believe it is.  There are good cases for both.  This site will not settle the matter.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/100064696956186/videos/3561755240736218